# Buidling XWiki-Platform. Maven dependency error

Tags: maven, xwiki

I've cloned the XWiki-Platform repository and now trying to build it.

After having some initial troubles, I am now stuck on this error:

> The POM for org.codehaus.swizzle:swizzle-confluence:jar:xwiki:1.2-20080419 is missing, no dependency information available
>
> Failed to execute goal on project xwiki-platform-xmlrpc-model: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.xwiki.platform:xwiki-platform-xmlrpc-model:jar:6.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.codehaus.swizzle:swizzle-confluence:jar:xwiki:1.2-20080419 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Maybe I'm missing something very obvious.
But I don't see why anything should be wrong at all, since it is a fresh clone.

So far my bust guess is that [this is the location](http://maven.xwiki.org/externals/org/codehaus/swizzle/swizzle-confluence/1.2-20080419/) of the `swizzle-confluence`, but the maven `pom` is not configured to look there.

PS. If anyone not related to the XWiki team would like to help, then this is a [good place to start](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-xmlrpc/xwiki-platform-xmlrpc-model/pom.xml#L39)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [Building XWiki](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/Building) documentation, you have to configure the custom [XWiki Nexus repository](http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/) for the build to work. Simply edit `~/.m2/settings.xml` and fill in the required settings.